# Excel: Calculate running balance for different group

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, r

I would like to calculate a running balance for a different group. For illustration, my table consists of the the following columns and data/information:

| Acct_Msisdn | Txn_Amount | created_on | Running Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Account A | 100 | 3/19/2021 | 100 |
| Account A | 200 | 3/20/2021 | 300 |
| Account A | 300 | 3/21/2021 | 600 |
| Account A | (400) | 3/22/2021 | 200 |
| Account B | 50 | 3/19/2021 | 50 |
| Account B | 100 | 3/20/2021 | 150 |
| Account B | 150 | 3/21/2021 | 300 |
| Account B | (200) | 3/22/2021 | 100 |
| Account C | 10 | 3/19/2021 | 10 |
| Account C | 20 | 3/20/2021 | 30 |
| Account C | 30 | 3/21/2021 | 60 |
| Account C | (40) | 3/22/2021 | 20 |

Currently I calculate the "Running Balance" column manually. That is, for each account (eg: Account A), Running balance = previous Running Balance + (or -) Txn_Amount.

Does anyone have a better idea instead of doing this manually?

If anyone can suggest a solution with R, that would also work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//Read in the data
// Change table name in next line to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],

//Group by "Acct_msisdn"
//  then add a running balanc column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Acct_Msisdn"}, {
        {"Running Balance", (t)=> let 
            rb=List.Generate(
                ()=>[rb=t[Txn_Amount]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx]<Table.RowCount(t),
                each [rb= [rb]+t[Txn_Amount]{[idx]+1}, idx = [idx]+1],
                each [rb]),
            addCol= Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(t) & {rb},
                Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Running Balance"}
            )
            in addCol}}),

//expand the subtable
// then set the data types
    #"Expanded Running Balance" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Running Balance", 
        {"Txn_Amount", "created_on", "Running Balance"}, 
        {"Txn_Amount", "created_on", "Running Balance"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Running Balance",{
        {"Acct_Msisdn", type text}, 
        {"Txn_Amount", Currency.Type}, 
        {"created_on", type date}, 
        {"Running Balance", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

***Data TAble***
[image]

***Result table with running balance***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SUMIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function.

Assuming your data list has its top left corner in cell `A1` then your Balance column is in column `D` with its first calculated value in cell `D2`. The following formula can be used in cell `D2`

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2)
```

Copy cell `D2` to subsequent cells in column `D` and this will keep a running balance of the different accounts identified in column `A`.

The formula works by using a mix of [absolute and relative addressing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9). It does not need the rows to be grouped together by account (as they are in your example data). It will work irrespective of the order of the rows of data.

Take care in the labelling of the accounts in column `A`. If you mis-label an account, eg you write "Acount A" instead of "Account A" in a row, then that row's value in column `B` will not get included in any Running Balance for Account A but you will instead create a running balance for any mislabelled rows called "Acount A". Even more difficult to identify will be mis-labels which contain a double space between "Account" and "A".

To avoid becoming the unwitting victim of such data entry errors I would be considering how to check that the sum of the balances across all expected accounts was consistent the sum of the values in column `B`. But that is another question.